# Basic CSS selector syntax, combining multiple ids and classes

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to be able to select any of the four individual spans below by their id and class (and nothing else) but I can't seem to find the right syntax... `#id1 .class2` and `#id2 .class2` select the two right hand elements OK but `#id1 .class1` and `#id2 .class1` seem to select both elements where I'd expect them to select only the first span in the p.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #id1 .class1{ background: red; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="id1">
            <span class="class1">one<span> 
            <span class="class2">two<span> 
        </p>
        <p id="id2">
            <span class="class1">three<span> 
            <span class="class2">four<span> 
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your CSS is fine.  You didn't close your spans:

```
<span>...<span>
```

should be

```
<span>...</span>
```

because of this, `class2` is really a child of `class1`.

Comment: Doh! Sometimes you can't see the wood for the trees! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
#id1 .class1 {}
#id1 .class2 {}
#id2 .class1 {}
#id2 .class2 {}
```